# Involvement of the use of scanner interfering with ImageIcon

Tags: java

I started a new project a couple days back and my program so far is a bunch of questions.  My project is a Pokemon quiz game where questions are asked and the user inputs responses. A unique response then changes some values.

I'm trying to get pictures of the Pokemon they got based on their points at the end of the quiz through GUI. I've created a label for them, and am using this line to display them:

```
GuiName.LabelName.set(new ImageIcon(filepath));
```

so heres my use of this code:

```
view.label1.set(new ImageIcon("Moves/squirtle.jpg"));
```

This seems to work fine at the beginning of my code, but as I begin to get deeper into the code, this line does not change the GUI label whatsoever. It seems that it is not even read, just ignored. I've tried setting the label in a different method, a different class, and in different ways but they all turn out of the same. The only one that seems to work is the first one before all the Scanners. Is Scanner interfering with my project some how? Can anyone help me out on this issue I've been stuck on a while now.

Comment: You are basically saying something worked and after some changes it stopped. Start removing what you added(possibly relevant things) until it starts working again to pinpoint the problem, or at least attach some stripped code that has the issue. From information in your question will be really hard to figure your problem out.

Comment: Sounds like you're having issues with the overuse of static